# Linking: Sibilant with Other Sibilants (was + starting)

Tags: pronunciation, consonants

I read in an American Accent book that there is no break between sibilants adjoining each other between words. For example, this phrase:

> I was starting to worry.

The words *was* + *starting* sound like [wə**zs**tɑrt̬ɪŋ] with no break. Am I right? I marked the sibilant sounds with bold.

I used the schwa sound in *was* because it's a function word and we usually give stress to content words and reduce the function words. I also used the tapped T in the word started.

Comment: Isn't that true of most phonetics: tow west, great tackle, play yellow, back kick, etc?

Comment: No break, no; but usually voicing assimilation does take place, so really you'd just have [s:] rather than [zs].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the assimilation sounds out of place to me in all but the most casual or rapid speech.

Comment: @phoog: Have you actually analyzed your speech phonetically, though? It can be hard to hear these kind of assimilations and accommodations by ear. I've read that often, words like "was" that end in a phonemic /z/ have the sound partially or fully devoiced to a phonetic [s] before a pause, but it still sounds voiced to an English speaker because there are secondary effects of the phonemic voicing, such as longer vowel length.

Comment: @sumelic, agreed.  Compare 'lees' and 'lease'.  Native speakers at least partly rely on the longer vowel in 'lees' to distinguish it from 'lease', but pretty well all dictionaries will say that they contain the same long-E sound /i:/.

Comment: @phoog Conversely, maintaining a clearly voiced [z] directly followed by a clearly unvoiced [s] is all but impossible to me in all but extremely and artificially prolonged and hyper-enunciated speech. Not even in careful speech would I have [zs]. It’s quite likely there’d be some initial voicing in the early part of the sibilant, but I find it _extremely_ difficult to keep up this voicing until the start of the stressed syllable. If we say the duration of the /zs/ = [sː] is, say, 120 ms, I’m guessing the voiced bit might last the first 25 ms at the most. Certainly not 60 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is never a break between words unless you make one.  You could say first the word "was", stop making sounds, then say "starting", if you chose to make that break.  If there is no period of silence between them, the [zs] pronunciation is just a [z] followed immediately by [s].

If you happen to be an English speaker who customarily devoices word-final obstruents, like /z/, then the last sound of "was" will be voiceless, but it would have been anyway, regardless of whether "starting" followed.  Details of how exactly word final /z/ is pronounced in various English dialects are interesting in themselves, but so far as I know, they have nothing to do with whether the next word starts with /s/.

Comment: Might be some assimilation.

Comment: @tchrist, I think a final /z/ which would otherwise be devoiced may assimilate and become voiced before a following vowel.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I generally at least partially devoice word-final obstruents, but _was a_ is still [wəzə] with full voicing. I think @tchrist meant the other way around, though: a non-devoiced (i.e., voiced) /z/ would also be likely to assimilate and become unvoiced before an unvoiced consonant, especially a homorganic /s/.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Was, despite ending with an 's' sounds like a 'z' with an American speaker no mater where you are. Because of that [wəstɑrt̬ɪŋ] isn't correct. That would only work if both the 's' in "was" and "starting" were pronounced the same. As for the lack of break, that would be correct as well. Even in a lengthened cadence such as in a Texan Drawl, it is really hard to separate them out into two distinct words and have it sound right.

Comment: Thanks. Your time greatly appreciated. It's good to know because there are a lot of such situations, for example: How was school? [haʊ wəzskuəl?]

Comment: 1) It’s not true that _was_ ends in a phonetic [z] no matter where you are. There are plenty of people (as Greg mentions in his answer) who customarily devoice word-final obstruents—I’m one of them. 2) Not only is [wəˈstɑɹɾn̩] not incorrect, it is by far the most common pronunciation in natural, improvised, rapid, American English speech. The two sibilants are reduced to one.

Comment: Janus Bahs Jacquet Thank you. I reduced the two sibilants to one ['haʊ wə'skuəl?]. Could you please provide me with a feedback on my pronunciation?  Does it sound natural after I reduced the two sibilants to one? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1924024/howwasschool.wav